# Any system of subset module imports in haskell?

Tags: perl, haskell

With Perl's [standard module exports](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Exporter-5.68/lib/Exporter.pm#Specialised_Import_Lists) you can specify sets of functions to export/import by tag.

So, you can have sets like `:all` or `:private` or `:test` or whatever.

Hisorically, the advice seems to be that if you just want some semi-private functions then have an "inner" module and re-export the "default" parts of it.

I'm starting to want a semi-private interface for testing purposes. So, is that still the way to do it, or am I missing something in a recent ghc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible in Haskell.

The Haskell solution to this problem is just to have separate modules. E.g.

```
module Foo.Private
  ( private1
  , private2
  , private3
  ) where

...

module Foo
  ( public1
  , public2
  , public3
  ) where

...
```

Additionally, if you want `Foo.Private` to re-export everything from `Foo`:

```
module Foo.Private
  ( module Foo
  , private1
  , private2
  , private3
  ) where

import Foo

...
```

But if `Foo` in turn imports `Foo.Private`, then you'll have either to use
recursive modules, or to move the actual definitions to a third module,
say `Foo.Base`, which would be imported by `Foo` and `Foo.Private`.

Also, unlike perl, ghc doesn't support defining multiple modules in the same
file [yet](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2551), which makes this solution somewhat heavyweight.

Comment: The "yet" in "ghc doesn't support defining multiple modules in the safe file yet" doesn't seem accurate, since the Trac bug it links to is closed as "wontfix".

Comment: It doesn't mean much. If someone comes up with a good pitch and implements the feature, I think it would have a high chance of adoption. Even the Monad/Applicative proposal is being implemented — everything is possible!

Answer (score 2):

You can import a subset of functions using this:

```
import Data.List (nub, sort)
```

That will only import `nub` and `sort` from the Data.List module. Say, in case you don't want something to be imported, then:

```
import Data.List hiding (sort)
```

This will import all the functions in Data.List module except the sort function.

And in case if you want to export only certain functions from your module then define them like this:

```
module Data.List
    ( sort,
      nub
    ) where
```

That will only export the `sort` and the `nub` functions in the module.

Comment: or `import qualified Data.Map as M`

Comment: That's not a subset - it's an explicit list of functions.

Answer (score 0):

[the haskell version of doctest](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/doctest) runs code such that the non-exported functions are in scope.

Comment: Thanks - interesting. The little I can grasp from the code suggests it does this by running the module through a library version of ghci.

Comment: right and ghci does that, provided the module is not loaded as compiled code (ie. when your prompt looks like `*M>` not `M>`)